# Page jumps back to top with window.scrollTo()

Tags: javascript

I want to jump to an `id` using a `hash` but after the scroll the page jumps back to the top:

```
if(window.location.hash != '' && typeof window.location.hash != 'undefined') {
  const loc = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  const locEl = document.getElementById(loc);
  const locPos = locEl.offsetTop;
  window.scrollTo(0,500);
}
```

Changing the `500` I can see it scrolling to specific areas but it always jumps back to the top.

Comment: Why are you declaring those constants? I don't see you using them in their scope. You are aware that these live only inside your `if { }` block?

Comment: I was using 500 to make sure the scroll was working. Placing `locPos` in the `scrollTo` works as well but it still jumps.

Comment: As a sidenote, why not simply do `if(window.location.hash) { ... }`?

Comment: @connexo you're right. I planned on correcting that once I got the scroll working.

Answer (score 0):

verify if in your html has #, if has is just remove it e try again